# Is it possible to code Metro apps with Python?

Tags: python, microsoft-metro, windows

is it possible to write Metro apps with Python? Because Python is my primary language.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a full application yet. The easiest path to that would be  to use a Python Binding for the CLR, such as IronPython. Unfortunately, they're still working on support.

There's clearly a lot of interest in adding support for Metro, since they even [had a work item in](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/31783), which has now been migrated to GitHub.

Citing their own documentation,

> Support for Android, Windows 8 Store Apps (Metro), Window Phone 8, and
>   iOS are also planned (in roughly that order).

When that happens, the project will be able to target the subset of the BCL that WinRT supports.

Answer (score 0):

No. Python is not a supported language for Windows Store apps.

That said, some people have ported python to run scripts in a Windows Store app (for example: [Python 3 for Metro](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/python-3-for-metro/82f0c953-93d4-461c-893f-c298b0d919d2)). The app itself is not written in python.